# Looping through array and get non-repeating values

Tags: php

I have an array of elements which I queried from the mongoDB.

This array has the id of a device and value of this device's consumptions.

For example there are 3 different ids -> 18,5,3 and multiple mixed values.

```
// first record of 18 so get value.
$row[0]["id"]    = 18;
$row[0]["value"] = 100;

// not first record of 18 so ignore and move to the next record
$row[1]["id"]    = 18;
$row[1]["value"] = 40;

// first record of 5 so get value.
$row[2]["id"]    = 5;
$row[2]["value"] = 20;

// not first record of 18 so ignore and move to the next record
$row[3]["id"]    = 18;
$row[3]["value"] = 30;

// first record of 3 so get value.
$row[4]["id"]    = 3;
$row[4]["value"] = 20;

//not first record of 5 so ignore and move to the next record**
$row[5]["id"]    = 5;
$row[5]["value"] = 30;

// not first record of 18 so ignore and move to the next record
$row[6]["id"]    = 18;
$row[6]["value"] = 10;


...
....
```

What I am trying to do is loop through this $row array and get the most recent value of the id.

For example in above example what I want to return is:

```
id   value
18    100 
5     20
3     20
```

How can I do that kind of logic?

Comment: So... if you are trying to loop... where is the loop?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: You mentionned first record of 5 is 20, but in your return value you put 40. Why ?

Comment: *t is not *most recent*, it is highest. It would be way more efficient to retrieve them from the db, rather than filter in php: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/

Comment: @AlexBlex I'm not getting the highest...

Comment: fair enough, thanks for editing the post. The mogodb function to get first item: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in several ways. The easiest one is to use a `foreach`:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($row as $i) {
    if (! array_key_exists($i['id'], $result)) {
        $result[$i['id']] = $i['value'];
    }
}

# Verify the result
print_r($result);
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [18] => 100
    [5] => 20
    [3] => 20
)
```

The same processing, but using [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$result = array_reduce(
    $row,
    function(array $c, array $i) {
        if (! array_key_exists($i['id'], $c)) {
            $c[$i['id']] = $i['value'];
        }
        return $c;
    },
    array()
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$alreadyfound = []; // empty array
$result = [];
foreach ($row as $item)
{
    if (in_array($item["id"], $alreadyfound))
        continue;
    $alreadyfound[] = $item["id"]; // add to array
    $result[] = $item;
}
```

The result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18
            [value] => 100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [value] => 20
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [value] => 20
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep only the first occurrence of each 'id' then just add the values to an aggregate array - but only if they haven't been added already.  Then grab the values of the aggregate array.

https://tehplayground.com/NRvw9uJF615oeh6C - press Ctrl+Enter to run

---

```
$results = array();
foreach ($row as $r) {
    $id = $r['id'];
    if (! array_key_exists($id, $results)) {
        $results[$id] = $r;
    }
}

$results = array_values($results);
print_r($results);
```

---

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18
            [value] => 100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [value] => 20
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [value] => 20
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

The array_unique() function is exactly what you are looking at.
See the documentation here : [array_unique() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Comment: You link to the french site. The english one is here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: Oops I didn't even pay attention, I've fixed the link, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `array_column` with an index key will almost do it, but it will be in the reverse order, so you can reverse the input so that it works.

```
$result = array_column(array_reverse($row), 'value', 'id');
```